# Question about associating models

Tags: activerecord

I'm working on a Dungeons and Dragons character database. I have two models, character and statistic. I want this to work where each character has one set of statistics. The problem is, when I create a new character, every character shares the same statistic information. This is probably a really easy problem to solve, but I've been butting my head up against it and can't figure it out.

Here's code from the character model:

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statistics, :dependent => :destroy
end

Here's code from the statistic model:

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
end

What's the proper code for displaying the statistic model when viewing the character? Do I need to use a link_to or a render tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is many of them, you'll need to use a loop or something:

```
<ul>
  <% @character.statistics.each do |stat| %>
    <li><%= stat %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Even better would be to use a partial:

```
<ul>
  <% @character.statistics.each do |stat| %>
    <%= render :partial => "characters/statistic", :object => stat %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Then you'll have app/views/characters/_statistic.html.erb:

```
<li><%= statistic %></li>
```

This way you can use the code for the statistic rendering in other places too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Another question, though. Since each character will only have one instance of the statistic model, do I need to declare has_many? At first, I thought has_one was the way to go, but then I thought it should be has_many since I will have more than one character instance. Which is the right way to go?

Comment: If the Character only has one statistic, then has_one is the way to go. Do you mean that each statistic will belong to many characters, or you'll just have multiple characters in your system?

Comment: I'll have multiple characters in the system. I'm assuming I'll want each character to have one instance of the statistic model, since each character will just have one set of statistics.

Comment: Hmm, so they have one _set_ of statistics? That would mean they have many statistics, so your original has_many/belongs_to setup was the right one. If it's D&D, I'm guessing that each character would have the 6 different statistics, which is a has_many relationship.

Comment: Yeah, each character will have 6 different stats. I'm still having the problem with all characters sharing the same stat, however. I'm not sure where I need to put the code you posted.

Comment: That code goes in a view for when you want to display the character. The same stat issue is probably because the foreign keys are not correctly set. The statistics table should have a character_id field which should be set to the id of the corresponding character.

Comment: I think this is where I first ran into trouble. How do I make that declaration? Does it go in the statistic model, the character model or both?

Comment: It should be in your migration that creates the statistics table. Something like t.integer :character_id although it has been a while since I did any Rails so the exact syntax might have changed.